# TableView data pass into another tableview with same UIVIewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I want to pass first tableview data into second tableview with same viewController when didSelectRowAt on first tableview.

```
var bidCreatedByBankerArray : [BidCreatedByBanker]? = nil
var tableData = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == tableView1{
        return (bidCreatedByBankerArray?.count)!
    }else{
        return (tableData.count)
    }  
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell1ID") as? NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell1
        let bidCreatedByBankerData = bidCreatedByBankerArray?[indexPath.row]
        cell?.projectDescriptionLabel.text = bidCreatedByBankerData?.projectDescription
        return cell!
    }else {
        let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2ID") as? NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2
        let bidCreatedByBankerData = tableData[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2
}
```

for me it's showing empty details when click on first tableview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to set datasource for second tableview when you click in first tableview

Comment: @Vinodh thank for quick responding, datasource means?

Comment: how you setting datasource to tableview in storyboard remove that and add programmatically

Comment: you are not setting text to label for NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2ID class in cell for row at indexpath

Comment: Ok.But here var tableData = [String](), So there is no any value in tableData..How can I set text to label?

Comment: after setting the data you need to see that text so set in cell for row at index path .

Answer (score 0):

your question seems a bit unclear. But I'm having a few assumptions here:

- Your both table views are in a same view controller.
- Passing data between views is meaning here to be linked with cell of your tableview as this is where all the data is placed or suppose it resides in your cell class object.

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 

     let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2
     // getting cell model object from controller instance array
     let bankerBid = bidCreatedByBankerArray?[indexPath.row]
     // assuming your data is in cell
     let data = cell?.dataNeeded
     // updating second table data
     tableData[indexPath.row] = bankerBid
     if tableView != tableView1 {
        tableView.reloadData()
     }

  }
  ```

If this isn't what you're asking for comment down below I'm happy to help!

Comment: let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2
        let bankerBid = bidCreatedByBankerArray?[indexPath.row]
        cell?.cityNameLabel.text = (bankerBid?.address)!
        tableData[indexPath.row] = bankerBid
        tableView2.dataSource = self
        tableView2.delegate = self
        if tableView != tableView1 {
            tableView1.reloadData()
        }

Comment: when setting tableData[indexPath.row] = bankerBid it's getting error " Cannot assign value of type 'BidCreatedByBanker?' to type 'String' "

Comment: It's because bankerBid is of type BidCreatedByBanker? and tableData stores value of type String. Remove dataSource and delegate from here. Put tableData[indexPath.row] = (bankerBid?.address)!

Comment: I have changed what u said .But it's getting error " Fatal error: Index out of range "

Comment: how you will have banker address in banker bid class .

Comment: @AmberK no need.. I got from #Vinodh ..He helped me a lot..thank u bro..

Answer (score 0):

```
var bidCreatedByBankerArray : [BidCreatedByBanker] = [BidCreatedByBanker]()
var tableData : [BidCreatedByBanker] = [BidCreatedByBanker]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!

extension NumberOfBidForBorrowerViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    //MARK: - TableView

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == tableView1{
            return (bidCreatedByBankerArray.count)
        }else{
            return (tableData.count)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
            let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell1ID") as? NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell1
            let bidCreatedByBankerData = bidCreatedByBankerArray[indexPath.row]
            cell?.projectDescriptionLabel.text = bidCreatedByBankerData.projectDescription
            return cell!
        }else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2ID", for: indexPath) as! NumberOfBidsForBorrowerTableViewCell2
            cell.selectionStyle = .default  
            let bidCreatedByBankerData = tableData[indexPath.row]

            cell.cityNameLabel.text = bidCreatedByBankerData.cityName
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView2.reloadData()
        if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
            tableView2.isHidden = false
            let bidCreatedByBankerData = bidCreatedByBankerArray[indexPath.row]
            tableData.removeAll()
            tableData.append(bidCreatedByBankerData)
            tableView2.reloadData()
        }
    } 
}
```